# Adding multiple reminder - windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, reminders

I have learned on how to create a reminder application from this website http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/f397b9/reminder-application-in-windows-phone-mango/
But from here it allows to just add one reminder. As I make a new reminder, the previous will be overrided. How do i make it to be able to accept multiple reminders. Below are my code:

```
void btnSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime _Date = rDate.Value.Value;
        TimeSpan _Time = rTime.Value.Value.TimeOfDay;
        _Date = _Date.Date + _Time;
        String _Content = titleTBox.Text;
        if (_Date < DateTime.Now)
            MessageBox.Show("Your time is not match !\nPlease Enter again !");
        else if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(_Content))
            MessageBox.Show("Your task can't be empty !\n Please enter to do task !");
        else
        {

            ScheduledAction _OldReminder = ScheduledActionService.Find("TodoReminder"); if (_OldReminder != null)
                ScheduledActionService.Remove(_OldReminder.Name);
            Reminder _Reminder = new Reminder("TodoReminder")
            {
                BeginTime = _Date,
                Title = "Reminder",
                Content = _Content,
            };
            ScheduledActionService.Add(_Reminder);
            //MessageBox.Show("Set Reminder Completed");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code is working as expected, you are finding a previously registered reminder, when it exists, you remove it and then register a new one with the same name.

separate your code into a simple method

```
 private void RegisterScheduleIfNotExist(string name, string title, string content, DateTime time)
    {
        ScheduledAction currentReminder = ScheduledActionService.Find(name);

        if (currentReminder != null)
        {
            ScheduledActionService.Remove(currentReminder.Name);
        }

        var reminder = new Reminder(name)
        {
            BeginTime = time,
            Title = title,
            Content = content,
        };

        ScheduledActionService.Add(reminder);
    }
```

then call the method with Unique names IF you do not wish to override an existing reminder, e.g.with Task1, Task2

```
RegisterScheduleIfNotExist("Task1", "Task 1 title", "Task 1 content", DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(3));

RegisterScheduleIfNotExist("Task2", "Task 2 title", "Task 2 content", DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(5));
```

Comment: Hi there, I have tested it out! It works perfectly fine! Thank you so much for the solution.